# How can I exclude .min.css files from an ack-grep seach?

Tags: ack

I've got the syntax of adding a new `ack-grep` filetype:

```
$ ack-grep --type-add=min=.min.js,.min.css --help types | grep min
    --[no]min          .min.js .min.css
```

But the problem is that it doesn't seem to ever match any files, possibly because my extensions (`.min.js` / `.min.css`) have 2 dots in them.

```
$ touch test.min.js
$ ack-grep --min -f
    [nothing returned]
```

So how can I make `ack-grep` recognise a filetype with 2 dots in it? And if that's not possible how can I search js and css files without matching minified versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ack will ignore min.js files as of 1.96. Seems this was included within a pull [request 142](https://github.com/petdance/ack/pull/142). As for CSS seems that wont happen in 1.x. There is though a pull request if you could  be bothered installing your own fork on [219](https://github.com/petdance/ack/issues/219).

Comment: No, it won't be in 1.x.  When 2.0 comes out (it's currently in beta) you'll have much more flexibility, including being able to match extensions via regex.

Comment: ack 2.0 is now out and it ignores minified JS and CSS.